# Blazor DynamicComponent not receiving State Changes for Data Changes in Parameters

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, webassembly

I have a multitude of custom subcomponents that will receive state updates if they are manually listed e.g.

```
<MyCustomComponent Data="@data" />
```

However, the DynamicComponent will not receive state changes to data if I set it up in a for loop with a Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>:

```
@foreach(var object in objects) {
    <DynamicComponent Type="@TypeDictionary[object.id]" Parameters="@myDoubleDictionary[object.id]" />
}
```

Is the automatic State detection not intended to work through DynamicComponent with a list/dictionary of the dictionaries, or am I missing something obvious here? This works if the dictionary is defined inline, but this doesn't work in a for loop if the objects contain different dictionaries depending on the object ID.

Comment: Check this way:

<DynamicComponent Type="@type" Parameters="@(new Dictionary<string, object>() {{"Data", data }})" />

Comment: Yes, this also works - specifically when the parameters are dynamic within the dynamiccomponent it fails, updated question

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've told us, here's a demo of it working.  I've added a button to provide an update mechanism.

`Component` and `Component1`

```cs
<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-1">
    <h3>@Data.TimeStamp</h3>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public Data Data { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And Index:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<div>
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=SetData>Update</button>
</div>
<DynamicComponent Type=typeof(Component) Parameters=_componentData />
<DynamicComponent Type=typeof(Component1) Parameters=_componentData />

@code {
    private Data _data = new();
    private Dictionary<string, object> _componentData => new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Data", _data } };
    
    private void SetData()
        => _data.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

Comment: Yep this works, I did not understand my own problem at the time of posting - the issue is reproducible with Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object> or List<Dictionary<string, object>>

Answer (score 0):

This appears to maybe be a bug, I will raise with the Blazor folks.

Whether I use a list or a dictionary to dynamically select a Parameter dictionary, State is not carried to the subcomponent for Parameters (even though the parameters are correct).

This can be solved by creating new dictionaries at "runtime", e.g.

```
@foreach(var object in objects) {
    <DynamicComponent Type="@TypeDictionary[object.id]" Parameters="@CreateNewParamDictionary(object.id)" />
}
```

...and of course:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> CreateNewParamDictionary(string id) {
    switch(id) {

    //logic, e.g. thisDict = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Data", data } };

    }
    return thisDict;
}
```